# direct nuget where to put files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, nuget-package

I am working with nuget and find it excellent with my MVC4 project. I use it for all my external dependencies.

I have run in to one small problem with it. For example, installing the jQuery package, it places the jQuery files in to the Scripts folder. My preference is that it places the javascript files in to a libraries folder within scripts. So instead of

```
Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js
```

I want to place it in

```
Scripts/libraries/jquery-1.8.3.js
```

Yes I can manually move it but then I lose the features of nuget. Any way that I can direct where a package places the files like this?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450907/asp-net-mvc-folder-structure-and-nuget. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450907/asp-net-mvc-folder-structure-and-nuget#8080229 if you really want to edit the location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported yet 
dupe of
[NuGet scripts to different directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989981/nuget-scripts-to-different-directory) 
, nuget codeplex issue is here http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1914