# How to install js library via nuget to specific folder?

Tags: javascript, nuget, nuget-package

Is there any way to install js libraries to the specific folder in the project?

By default Nuget installs it to `Scripts` folder of the project, but I need to install it into `/Scripts/BlaBla/` for example.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC folder structure and NuGet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450907/asp-net-mvc-folder-structure-and-nuget)