# How do I specify the directory where NuGet packages are installed?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

How to do to specify the directory where I want install package? Because I need install packages in a project where others devs work and when they do download of the project they need have all packages in your pc.

Comment: I'm using nuget.config in my solution to specify packages path like this http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Use `-OutputDirectory`.**

From [NuGet CLI reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install).

Answer (score 8):

The packages go in $(SolutionDir)\packages. You have two options:

1. Check the packages folder into source control
2. Use [NuGetPowerTools](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/NuGetPowerTools) so that developer machines will automatically fetch the packages when you build

   - Type "Install-Package NuGetPowerTools" in the Package Manager Console
   - Type "Enable-PackageRestore" in the Package Manager Console

     - This adds a $(SolutionDir).nuget folder, which contains an MSBuild target that will fetch the packages when they're required (eg. if you build on a machine that doesn't already have them). **You must check the .nuget folder, and associated csproj changes into source control!!**

I'd recommend **not** checking the packages folder in, since binary files in DVCS make for slow clones :-( In the next version of NuGet, you won't need NuGetPowerTools to avoid checking it in :-)

Comment: If you get a "Failed to add import 'NuGet.targets' to XXX" error while following these steps, see here: https://github.com/davidfowl/NuGetPowerTools/issues/22

Answer (score 5):

You can now change the default `$(SolutionDir)\packages` folder. See this thread: [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)