# How do you query installed nuget packages with the command line interface?

Tags: nuget

I need to find the installed version of a package inside my CI build script using the nuget command line.

The "list" command returns ALL packages from the nuget.org feed as far as I can tell.  I only want the locally installed packages.

I know how to do this with the VS nuget powershell console.  Please do not answer "use get-package".  I need to do it with the nuget.exe.

However if there's a way to use the nuget command from plain powershell outside of visual studio that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

`nuget list -Source http://my.local.feed/` will list packages available in a *local* feed, and `dir .\packages` from within the top-level solution folder will show the packages installed under that location (where `.\packages` is the install location you have set for the solution).

From http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#List_Command_Options and [How do I specify the directory where NuGet packages are installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676640/how-do-i-specify-the-directory-where-nuget-packages-are-installed)

Comment: I guess `dir packageFolder` would sorta work, but packages is global to the whole project.  I ended up manually parsing the packages.config.

Comment: Doesn't work if you use package restore enabled (which you usually should).