# Use two NuGet packages with the same .dll name in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to use two NuGet packages in my Visual Studio project which has the same output path; so, when I try to build, Visual Studio gives me

> Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'MyNugetPackage.dll'

Is it possible to change the output .dll name of a NuGet library? If it's, how can I do this?

Thank you

EDIT: If someone is wondering why I want to load two version of the same package, that's because I'm trying to use ApplicationInsights in WP 8.1 Silverlight and RT projects with some shared code. I'm also using background tasks. The SL app uses the same bgtask as RT, so I need to load at the same time the RT and the SL packages of ApplicationInsights for the SL app.

Comment: Download the nupkg file, unpack and rename the dll file. BUT, make sure that they don't share namespace or something that can collide.

Comment: If I go this way, I'll lose all Nuget updates. I can't believe there's not a way to change the output name of the dll!

Comment: It is not intended to work like this. A package name, dll, is intended to be unique. or try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676640/how-do-i-specify-the-directory-where-nuget-packages-are-installed

Comment: Are you trying to use 2 versions of the same package? If so, why?

Comment: I'm trying to use ApplicationInsights in WP 8.1 Silverlight and RT projects with some shared code. I'm also using background tasks. The SL app use the same bg task as RT, so I need to load at the same time the RT and the SL packages of ApplicationInsights.