# Load unreferenced Dll

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I'm trying to load `System.Data.SqlClient` dynamically.

The `System.Data.SqlClient` Nuget is installed but there is no reference to it in the project.

And I don't know the right path to the nuget directory.

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Here is my code

```
internal static Type GetFastType(this string typeName, string assembly)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(assembly))
        throw new Exception("AssemblyName cannot be empty");

    if (!assembly.ToLower().EndsWith(".dll"))
        assembly += ".dll";
    var key = typeName + assembly;
    if (CachedStringTypes.ContainsKey(key))
        return CachedStringTypes.Get(key);

    // Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly) // throw exception as the dll is not found
    if (!CachedAssembly.ContainsKey(assembly))
        CachedAssembly.Add(assembly, Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly));

    return CachedStringTypes.GetOrAdd(key, CachedAssembly.Get(assembly).GetType(typeName, true, true));
}
```

And here is how I run it

```
var type ="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection".GetFastType("System.Data.SqlClient");
```

Comment: What is `CachedAssembly`?

Comment: It a `Dictionary<string, Assembly>` containe already loaded `Assembly`

Comment: Yes i know, I installed the nuget package, but i dont know the full path.

Comment: I guess your `CachedAssembly.TryAdd` is returning false, but you are not checking it.

Comment: My problem is this line return an error `Assembly.LoadFrom(assembly)`

Comment: *"i dont know the right path to the nuget directory"* - why? Can't you [specify it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7676640/1997232)?

Comment: Its a library and diffrent platform and user have diffrent settings.

Comment: *"I installed the nuget package"* - how you did it?

Answer (score 3):

### Required reading:

Read this MSDN article: [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading)

### In short:

It looks like you're assuming the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` class always exists inside `System.Data.SqlClient.dll`.

This is an incorrect assumption:

- A NuGet package is not a .NET assembly.
- A NuGet package does not map 1:1 with a .NET assembly nor namespaces.
- A NuGet package can contain multiple assemblies.
- A NuGet package can contain zero assemblies.
- A NuGet package can contain assemblies that don't have any types defined in them at all!

  - They could be assemblies that only contain Resources or other embedded items
  - They could be assemblies that use Type-Forwarding to redirect types that previously existed in this assembly other assemblies. Only the JIT uses this feature, however, not reflection.

    - And those "forwarded-to" assemblies don't have to exist in NuGet packages either: they can be "in-box" assemblies built-in to the runtime like `mscorlib.dll` and `System.Data.dll`).
  - They could be stub assemblies that don't provide any types when those types are already provided by the Base Class Library - the NuGet package only exists to provide those types for other platforms.

    - This is the situation you're dealing with.
- A NuGet package can have very different effects based on the project's target (.NET Framework, .NET Standard, .NET Core, etc)

**Your code cannot assume that a specific class is located in a specific assembly file** - this breaks .NET's notion of backwards-compatibility through type-forwarding.

### In your case...

In your case, your code assumes `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` exists inside an assembly file named `System.Data.SqlClient`. This assumption is false in many cases, but true in some cases.

Here is the top-level directory structure of the `System.Data.SqlClient` NuGet package:

[image]

Observe how inside the package there are subdirectories for each supported target (in this case, MonoAndroid10, MonoTouch10, net46, net451, net461, netcoreapp2.1, netstandard1.2, etc). For each of these targets the package provides **different assemblies**:

- When targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1, .NET Framework 4.6 or .NET Framework 4.6.1 the files from the `net451`, `net46` and `net461` directories (respectively) will be used. These folders contain a single file named `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` which **does not contain any classes**. This is because when you target the .NET Framework 4.x, the `System.Data.SqlClient` (namespace) types are already provided by the Base Class Library inside `System.Data.dll`, so there is no need for any additional types. (So if you're building only for .NET Framework 4.x then you don't need the `System.Data.SqlClient` NuGet package at all.

  Here's a screenshot of the insides of that assembly file using the .NET Reflector tool (a tool which lets you see inside and decompile .NET assemblies) if you don't believe me:

  [image]
- When targeting other platforms via .NET Standard (i.e. where `System.Data.dll` isn't included by default, or when `System.Data.dll` does not include `SqlClient`) then the NuGet package will use the `netstandard1.2`, `netstandard1.3`, `netstandard2.0` directories, which **does** contain a `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` that **does** contain the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace with the types that you're after. Here's a screenshot of that assembly:

  [image]
- And other platforms like `MonoAndroid`, `MonoTouch`, `xamarinios`, `xamarintvos`, etc also have their own specific version of the assembly file (or files!).

But even if you know your program will only run on a single specific platform where a specific NuGet package contains an assembly DLL that contains a specific type - it's still "wrong" because of type-forwarding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/type-forwarding-in-the-common-language-runtime

While Type-Forwarding means that most programs that reference types in certain assemblies will continue to work fine, it does not apply to reflection-based assembly-loading and type-loading, which is what your code does. Consider this scenario:

- A new version of the `System.Data.SqlClient` NuGet package comes out that now has two assemblies:

  - `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` (which is the same as before, except `SqlConnection` is removed but has a `[TypeForwardedTo]` attribute set that cites `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.dll`).
  - `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.dll` (the `SqlConnection` class now lives in this assembly).
- Your code will now break because it explicitly loads only `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` and not `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.dll` and enumerates those types.

### Here be dragons...

Now, assuming you're prepared to disregard all of that advice and still write programs that assume a specific type exists in a specific assembly, then the process is straightforward:

```
// Persistent state:
Dictionary<String,Assembly> loadedAssemblies = new Dictionary<String,Assembly>();
Dictionary<(String assembly, String typeName),Type> typesByAssemblyAndName = new Dictionary<(String assembly, String typeName),Type>();

// The function:
static Type GetExpectedTypeFromAssemblyFile( String assemblyFileName, String typeName )
{
    var t = ( assemblyFileName, typeName );
    if( !typesByName.TryGetValue( t, out Type type ) )
    {
        if( !loadedAssemblies.TryGetValue( assemblyFileName, out Assembly assembly ) )
        {
            assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom( assemblyFileName );
            loadedAssemblies[ assemblyFileName ] = assembly;
        }
        type = assembly.GetType( typeName ); // throws if the type doesn't exist
        typesByName[ t ] = type;
    }
    return type;
}

// Usage:

static IDbConnection CreateSqlConnection()
{
    const String typeName         = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection";
    const String assemblyFileName = "System.Data.SqlClient.dll";

    Type sqlConnectionType = GetExpectedTypeFromAssemblyFile( assemblyFileName, typeName );

    Object sqlConnectionInstance = Activator.CreateInstance( sqlConnectionType ); // Creates an instance of the specified type using that type's default constructor.
    return (IDbConnection)sqlConnectionInstance;
}
```

Comment: the project refer to multiplatforms netstandard, core and net451. the problem im having is not locating a type but loading the Assembly. Assembly.LoadFrom think that the dll is locating in the bin map but its not. the nuget packages is installed but cus there is no references to System.Data.SqlClient in the entire project then vs will not copy the dll from the packages to the bin file. and thats why Assembly.LoadFrom will throw an exception in netstandard 2.0 and coreapp 2.0. but it will work in the full net framework. So the anser you provided still wont work.

Comment: @Alen.Toma What happens if you specify the full absolute filename? What is the exact error or exception detail that occurs? I note that you probably shouldn't be doing any of this - **what are you really wanting to accomplish? Why can't you use `SqlConnection` directly?**

Comment: The exception is that it could not locate the `System.Data.SqlClient.dll`

Comment: @Dal Im building a multiproviders library, that support sqlclient, sqlite etc. i cant have the user install all these libraries at all times. with the method above the user could choose what to work with, and then the library will only load the required dll etc Provider.

Comment: @Alen.Toma That's fine - but for that you should use MEF or MAF (`System.AddIn`) instead of trying to make your own assembly loader. At the very least you can do type-discovery (using `Assembly.GetTypes()` to find what you want after loading assemblies, instead of assuming which specific assembly files should be loaded.

Comment: Well there we have something new, could u show me an example

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may have hade the same problem, i found the solution

Here is how you could load the right type in the right way

```
 var type = Type.GetType($"{typeName}, {assembly}");
 eg.
 var type =Type.GetType("System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data.SqlClient");
```

This way, it should load the dll dynamicly.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to provide the full path to `LoadFrom(...)`. You should be aware of the probing path of the application, so just concat that path to the name of the assembly. I don't think is straighforward to load from a path that is not in the probing path unless doing some thricks with the app domain.