# Nuget how can i specify packages location?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, package, nuget, nuget-package

[image]

i have simple folder structure:

```
project1
|_ nuget.config http://tinyurl.com/84ynb9z
|_ packages.config http://tinyurl.com/72zpy3z
project2
|_ nuget.config http://tinyurl.com/84ynb9z
|_ packages.config http://tinyurl.com/72zpy3z
packages
|_ FluentNHibernate.1.2.0.712
|_ FluentValidation.3.2.0.0
```

i need to restore packages from packages.config file (very trivial)

im using new function in nuget 1.6 that can restore packages when building, but i have 2 issues with it:

1. packages always "installed" in root folder. i tried to change NuGet.targets file a lot of times with a lot of variations but it always installed in root :(
2. it shows that packages installed (http://tinyurl.com/7f2ow6k) but nothing updated in References

btw:

im using nuget 1.6

i read http://goo.gl/zZabG and http://goo.gl/mJL7N already but nothing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)

Answer (score 0):

I update my Nuget.targets file that way, and the next build installed my packages in the "libs" directory

```
<PackagesDir>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(SolutionDir), "libs"))</PackagesDir>
```

but, references are not updated.

References are fixed by the first install. Then you have to re-install your packages (uninstall and then re-install), it will use the nuget.config file.

Then, for further builds, the NuGet.targets will used.

Not very intuitive but it works for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with NuGet when using a different folder to install packages than the default location :

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1990

It's currently assigned to be fixed in NuGet 1.9.