# NuGet scripts to different directory

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Nuget packages download Javascript files to ~/Scripts

I prefer to keep my content organized in a ~/content folder, which contains

```
~/content/css
~/content/images
~/content/scripts
~/content/scripts/vendor (for packages/ downlaoded scripts)
~/content/scripts/site (my own site's JS)
```

How do I make Nuget download Javascript files to `~/content/scripts/vendor`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

At the moment, NuGet doesn't support installing packages resources elsewhere than the default location. There's an existing NuGet work item that would cover this feature : [#1914  - Allow package resource folders to be configurable](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1914).

Comment: Yeah, would be nice to have this feature, maybe something like this: http://i.imgur.com/4f308dT.png

Comment: Don't understand why a work item with 200+ votes isn't resolved after more than 2 years.

Comment: Because NuGet is an afterthought. It's only a light clone of gem/npm. I cant tell you the effort ASP.net / MVC developers will exert to rearrange the files of a lib to match the default project format, and never question anything about it.

Comment: @Gigi2m02 over 3 years and counting now.

Comment: @gnack Things has changed the last few years, so I don't expect it will ever change. See my added answer below.

Comment: We are reaching 2017 and this hasn't been implemented yet... I love how it has been scheduled to `Soonish` release, but it's been more than 4 years already.

Comment: 2017 and nothing. I guess we won't see this

Comment: End of 2018, entering 2019 almost...7 years, still nothing

Answer (score 9):

Not really an 'answer', but worth noting:
With the shift of managing front-end libraries to Bower, I don't expect [work item #1914](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1914) will ever be implemented. 
I'd highly recommend to look into how you can use the combination of NPM, Bower and Grunt to achieve your custom folder structure.

If you had an early look at VS2015, you'll notice that's the new recommended way for your project set-up and maintenance.

**Bower**

> Dependency management tool used for managing front end components writting in html, css, jss (e.g. Bootstrap, Knockout, Angular, moment, lightboxes, gallery libraries, ...)

**NPM**

> Dependency management tool used for managing node js modules

**Grunt**

> Grunt is a javascript task runner tool. You can do a lot of things using grunt which you had to do manually otherwise: compiling files, linting files, moving files, ...

Difference between above three explained in detail here: [Difference between Grunt, NPM and Bower ( package.json vs bower.json )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198977/difference-between-grunt-npm-and-bower-package-json-vs-bower-json)