# How do I add dll files to a C# project and use them properly?

Tags: c#, dll, xna, xna-4.0

I need to add dll files (The XNA Framework) to a C# project and then be able to use them properly. This is so that I can send my solution to another person who doesn't have XNA installed and still have the project compile and run.

I'm trying to do this as part of a test, I need to program a game and then send the code to a person who will mark it. I am allowed to use public libraries but the project must compile without any additional steps on the marker's part.

Any additional information required don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks!

Comment: just put them into solution directory and reference them from there

Comment: I had thought about this but had no way to test it. When the solution is copied to a new computer under a new directory will the reference still point to the correct place?

Comment: @JosephLittle sure you have a way to check. just copy the whole solution to somewhere else to break the old path

Comment: There could be additional complications if some dll files are native. I had problems when installing ASP.NET web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a best practice to create a folder solution called "lib" and add all libraries used in your project to that folder. And yes, if you redistribute your solution paths will match.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NuGet (if you've got VS 2010+).  You will need to modify the location for where the 'packages' folder gets stored.

To do this, take a look at this link : [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)

The advantage to this is that you will be told when an update is available for the package.