# Change the location of packages for NuGet using the release note 2.1 doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to change the location of the default package folder for NuGet

I read many posts including the documentation of the [NuGet 2.1 Release Notes](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1#Specify_%E2%80%98packages%E2%80%99_Folder_Location), the new config for NuGet version 2.1 as the following:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key=" repositoryPath" value=" C:\myteam\teampackages" />
  </config>
  ... 
</configuration>
```

I also read the following thread, [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)

**But this configuration doesn't work?**

The only config work is the old one which is as the following:

```
<settings>
  <repositoryPath>C:\myteam\teampackages</repositoryPath>
</settings>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 that including NuGet Package version 2.1

Steps to reproduce:

- in solution directory, create a file "nuget.config"
- edit nuget.config and add:

> <settings>
>   <repositoryPath>C:\myteam\teampackages</repositoryPath>
>   
>   </settings>

- Delete the default packages folder
- In visual studio, right-click on Solution, and select Manage NuGet
  Packages Install a package (any package)
- Verify that package was downloaded to  *C:\myteam\teampackages*
- delete the downloaded package in *C:\myteam\teampackages*
- change the nuget.config to the following:

> <configuration>
>           <config>
>           <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\myteam\teampackages" />
>           </config>
>           </configuration>

Try to install any library again.

I find the library installed in the packages folder not my folder???

Comment: Did you try reloading the solution (close and re-open) after adding the nuget.config with the 2.1 release note settings?

Comment: Yes, I even restart the Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

>>steps to reproduce:

>>in solution directory, create a file "nuget.config"
From the release notes it looks for nuget.config in the following order
.nuget\nuget.config
Recursive walk from project (.nuget) folder to root
Global nuget.config (%appdata%\NuGet\nuget.config)

So if nuget.config is in the project/solution folder it won't be honored. Can you try moving it to .nuget folder and reload the solution.

Answer (score 2):

It works when you place a \ at the end of the path:

```
<add key=" repositoryPath" value="C:\myteam\teampackages\" />
```