# Install nuget packages to central folder

Tags: nuget

For the life of me I can't find an option to install all nuget packages to a central folder.

The only option seems to be Install and that always installs into the project folder.

With multiple projects using the same packages this is very inefficient.
I'd like to install all packages to the same central folder.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here: [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget/)

I successfully tried it with VS2012 and the latest nuget manager.