# How to put Nuget libraries on a folder

Tags: nuget

i generally add any library from Nuget to my project like issuing this command

```
Install-Package Mvc3Futures
```

then i have seen everything related to that library just added in my project. some one told me that library can be added to folder and later we can add that folder to my project like this way `tools > options > package manager - add your folder .`

really i have no idea how we can add library to any folder from Nuget. if it is possible then please show me the way in step-by-steps. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a step-by-step, but you can relocate/specify the place of the packages folder: [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget). But this way all of your packages location will change, I don't think you can do that per package. During installation you can specify where you install the package *from* (but not *to*): http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference, see Install Command.