# Am I free to move / choose a custom file location for scripts installed by Nuget packages and still get them updated?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

In addition to [controlling solution packages folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)  and away from it, do I have the right to move files of a VS2013 solution package like jQuery and jQuery UI to a different folder than solution1/Scripts and get them updated later? can I chose a custom location while install or at any stage?

Comment: Funny you asked... I JUST did this last night for an assignment at school

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Nugent just makes installing a little easier.. You'll just need to change your links to your scripts folder to wherever you saved them to.

How to install packages in a different location from the default "Packages" folder?

This can be done by setting the "repositoryPath" settings in nuget.config.
More Details and step by step [Here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1)

Comment: I already have external folder for packages installed and my problem now is to use /solution/project/scripts/lib/jquery instead of project/Scripts

Comment: So its actually in the scripts folder... You just added another folder called lib ? and its in there ?

Comment: they never get updated when install jquery new versions (1.9.1 to 2.10)

Comment: Nuget just install new library

Comment: which part on the link do you think it has any relation with my question? .. this is a different issue.

Comment: So let me get this right, You can install and use to where ever... but you want them to update in the new location where you've stored them ?

Comment: yes .. I think this how it should be .. there is a variable in jquery and most scripts package install.ps1 which is $scriptsFolderProjectItem

Comment: If you just want to update existing installs... follow this guide.. http://www.developerfusion.com/article/131917/using-nuget-packages/

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. Like @hsobhy I would like to change de path from Scripts to Shared\Scripts\jQuery or some other subfolder for each plugin.
At this moment when you move the scripts to the new path NuGet wont update the files when they're available. 
Is there no way to achieve this?