# How to add AngularJS with different modules to a Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

So far I thought that using Nuget to add the AngularJS modules is the way to go. But nuget adds the packages to whatever directory it is configured to. For example it adds the angularjs.core package to my main Scripts folder. It adds the angular-ui-router module again to my Scripts folder. But the angular-ui-bootstrap module is added to Scripts\angular-ui. If I am to use Nuget and keep the packages up to date, etc. I need to stick with this, which is inconsistent. Not to speak that I want to have all my angularjs scripts in a Scripts/vendors folder.

Can I somehow work around this problem or just ditch Nuget for this?

Comment: See this post, that will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget

Comment: Yes I read it but it has to do with the location of the packages folder rather than the location of the files themselves. I would like to control where the .js files are being placed relative to the solution.