# Can't create new projects in VS2013 -- most references are missing

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

About a week ago I noticed strange behavior with my install of Visual Studio 2013 Pro. Creating new projects always results in missing references to EntityFramework and most of the Microsoft.* components. I had reinstalled .NET 4.5 in repair mode around that time but can't recall if this problem happened before or after that install.

As it stands, I can no longer create a functioning project. I have an existing project I'm working on that will compile and run without issue, but creating any new projects (which I need for spike solutions etc) is no longer possible until this is fixed.

Screenshots follow. These are all from creating a new MVC project with all defaults accepted.

- [References list showing missing references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRudc.png)
- [Error list upon building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkJE2.png)
- [Reference paths are empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFOcC.png) (this was mentioned in another answer that did not directly address my specific question, so I'm including it)
- [Regedit showing .NET versions installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQLwh.png)

Even though I have "repaired" .NET 4.5 it appears from regedit that I only have up to .NET 4 installed? Am I reading that correctly?

Also, due to network restrictions I **cannot** download packages from Nuget automatically -- I have to download them manually from a laptop off-network and then sneakernet them over to install. The network physically blocks all connections to Nuget, github, etc.

If allowing VS to connect to Nuget is the only viable option then I have considered installing VS on the laptop, creating the project there and installing all necessary dependencies, and then moving the project folder over to the restricted computer and continuing from there. But I don't know if that is a solution to this problem or not.

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

.

Answer (score 1):

> The network blocks all connections to Nuget, github, etc.

It's almost like they don't want you to be productive.

Anyway the project templates (which you seem to be talking about) reference specific NuGet packages. Packages by default are stored relative to your solution.

[Place a nuget.config in your disk's root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget) (or any point into your projects directory, if you keep them organized like `C:\Dev\Visual Studio\Projects`, then each of those subfolders will be file) and point in that file to a shared package directory on your development machine. Here you can dump all packages you require.

Comment: Yes I agree, but my organization is extremely large and has very strict security rules, and I am a tiny cog in one tiny corner of it. So them's the rules unfortunately. :(  I'll take a look at the link and see if that helps. I will say that I have already manually configured VS to use a local nuget repository for the packages I've downloaded manually. Do I need to pull each of the missing packages shown in the screenshot from nuget and install them manually? I can do that, I just wasn't sure exactly what the problem was or if that would actually solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that should do it. It is also possible that for your working project, you have more recent packages, while the packages referenced from the project template (i.e. your new project) are older versions that aren't in your local repository. Try "Manage NuGet packages for Solution" and update all.