# How to install nuget package files to specific locaton in the project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Let say for example by default package `bootstrap less` files goes to:

less files goes to `Content\bootstrap`
js files goes to `Scripts`

I want less files goes to my custom folder `Content\less\bootstrap` and js files goes to folder `Content\js\bootstrap`

Is it possible to configure package installation foldres this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is not possible since package files are added to your project in the same structure they added to the nuget package. For example bootstrap package most probably look like this:

```
Scripts\bootstrap.js
Content\bootstrap\bootstrap.less
```

So if you project already has a Scripts folder `bootstrap.js` is going to be added to this folder otherwise Scripts folder is going to be created together with `bootstrap.js`.

One thing that you can do, is to specify the root location for all your packages in the project ([detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)), but I believe this is not what you are looking for.