# How to set output subfolder to copy reference dll to on build

Tags: c#, build, csproj, output-directory

Project References dlls are copied on build to the root of output directory (if `<Private>True</Private>` is set for this reference at `.csproj`, or `Copy Local` is set to `True` at reference properties in VisualStudio)

I have NuGet-package dependency of some 3rd-party dll & want this dll to be copied to some **subfolder** of output dir on build. How can this be done?

PS: I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370389/build-output-reference-assemblies-to-subfolder) question. But there is no answer appropriate for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find better way, than just let them be coppied to output root & then move them to my subfolder by adding this instruction to `.csproj`:

```
  <!-- Move some dlls into /MySubfolder -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareForRunDependsOn>$(PrepareForRunDependsOn);MyMoveDllsToOutputSubdir</PrepareForRunDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="MyMoveDllsToOutputSubdir">
    <Move SourceFiles="$(OutDir)\Aaa.dll;$(OutDir)\Aaa.pdb" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\MySubfolder" />
  </Target>
```