# Relocate %USERPROFILE%\.dotnet and .nuget to non-OS drive dotnet core 2.0 preview

Tags: nuget, .net-core, dotnet-restore

### Question

Can the folder `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet` and `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget` be relocated to non-OS drive (in my case D: drive).

### Constraints

1. I use a VM which is provisioned by organization I work for; with limited space in OS drive.
2. We are asked to save data to a different drive which has sufficient enough space and could be expanded.
3. I cannot edit system environment variables. I can only add/edit environment variables at User scope / level.

### Activities performed

I have futile attempts the following suggestions already  -

1. Edit the `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.config` file and change the value for key - `CliFallbackFolder`, and `globalPackagesFolder`.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <packageSources>
       <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
       <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="D:\nuget\packages" /> 
       <add key="CliFallbackFolder" value="D:\dotnet\NuGetFallbackFolder" /> 
     </packageSources>
   </configuration>`

   a. The value for `CliFallbackFolder` gets reset to `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet` next time I run dotnet restore
2. I have defined `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable @ user scope and have set its value to non-OS drive. **affects only the .nuget folder location **
3. I SO'ed this question and have already seen (with problem still persisting) -

   a. https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4003 (**Question on the .dotnet folder is not responded**)

   b. [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget) (**focuses on the .nuget folder and not on the .dotnet\CliNuGetFallbackFolderFallbackFolder**)
4. Raised an issue in github. I realized that I have committed a mistake by raising an issue in preview 3 of the code branch. 
   I also realized this is more a question than a issue, thus posting the question here. (https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7256)

### dotnet --info output

.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0-preview2-006497)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0-preview2-006497
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  06a2093335

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0-preview2-006497\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
  Version  : 2.0.0-preview2-25407-01
  Build    : 40c565230930ead58a50719c0ec799df77bddee9

### dotnet nuget --version

NuGet Command Line
4.3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **first part of the question** -

> Can the folder `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet` be relocated to non-OS drive (in my case D: drive).

**Answer is**

As of dotnet core 2.0.0-preview2-006497, it is not possible. The folder in question is part of SDK and is expected to be located in `%USERPROFILE%` directory.

[github response on the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7256)

I still feel for the constraints listed above, it is essential that at least in future versions it should be enabled.

The question which is still open is

> Can the folder `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget` be relocated to non-OS drive (in my case D: drive).

Please do share suggestions and do mind the steps already taken as an attempt to achieve the goal in the first post.