# Package destination of restore of .net-core projects is always global package directory

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

We have a solution in which some projects are .net-core projects and some are "normal" .net 4.6.1 projects.
On solution level we have a NuGet.config-File which sets the repositoryPath:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

The packages listed in the projects packages.config-Files are getting downloaded into the path specified in Nuget.config -> repositoryPath but the packages specified in the .net-core Project files (via PackageReference) are all downloaded into the global package directory in C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages.

It doesn't matter if i use Visual Studio 2017 or do it manually via nuget.exe.
The .net-core projects just ignore the NuGet.config.

What are we doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. This is the way the new project-system handles nuget-packages

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3135

Comment: @D.J. this is somewhat unintuitive. i want to decide where to put the packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay. Got it. Adding the following tag to the `.csproj` file does the trick:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
      ...
      <RestorePackagesPath>packages</RestorePackagesPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Source: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-settings-in-MSBuild

Answer (score 3):

`respositoryPath` is used for packages.config projects

`globalPackagesFolder` is used for PackageReference projects

Since packages.config and PackageReference use different folder formats these project types cannot use the same folder for packages, which is why there are two different config settings.