# Visual Studio 2017 Nuget.config at solution folder not recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I'm having issue with visual studio 2017,

where new solution keeps referencing the Nuget.config file in unexpected location in 'C:\Users\yopa\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\Nuget.config'.

I've added '/.nuget/Nuget.config' file to my solutions folder.

However, the solution is still referencing the nuget configuration file in the 'C:\', and the nuget packages are being restored in 'C:\' package folder as well.

How do I configure my solution to honour package.config file in its directory?

I've tried deleting the nuget.config file in the roaming folder, but the solution re-creates the file when nuget package restore is done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How do I configure my solution to honour package.config file in its directory?

To make sure your solution to honor the package.config file in the `.nuget` folder, you should configure this file correctly, for example, I created a test sample solution, then add a `Nuget.config` inside `.nuget` folder:

My `NuGet.Config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="D:\Test" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

Then, another important info is remember **restart Visual Studio** after adding the `Nuget.config` file.

As test result, the  nuget packages are being restored in 'D:\Test' package folder:

[image]

Comment: Can't stress this enough, the key here is **restart Visual Studio**. Just wasted two hours of my life trying to figure this out then found this answer!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like solution wide `Nuget.config` inside `.nuget` folder is no longer supported.

> NuGet 3.3 and earlier used a .nuget folder for solution-wide settings. This file is not used in NuGet 3.4+.

Config file should be placed at the project level or any folder in the project path instead, check documentation for additional details 
[Configuring nuget behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior).

Comment: Just noticed that in reality in a vs2019 v16.11.2 with nuget package manager v5.11.0 I still had to move the nuget.config file into the .nuget folder before it took effect though.

Comment: @BorisCallens Works fine for me with nuget.config in the sln root folder. It does require VS restart though to detect any changes there.

Comment: ah, maybe it was the restart :)