# What is the correct way to deploy a .NET application when building from IDE

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a solution that contains 2 projects: a class library called `plugin` and a console app called `myconsole`. They both use a NuGet package i.e. `log4net`. They have to meet these requirements:

- `myconsole` is not allowed to reference `plugin.dll`, but it needs to load it via reflection at run time
- `plugin.dll` has to be available in a directory called `plugins` that is relative to `myconsole.exe`
- `log4net.dll` has to be available in a directory called `dlls` that is also relative to `myconsole.exe`

I need this deployment to happen when I build the solution in the IDE. Ideally I need this file structure to be produced by the IDE build:

```
[Z:\Staging]
- [Dlls]
  - log4net.dll
- [Plugins]
  - plugin.dll
- myconsole.exe
```

I was thinking to update each project and add a MSBuild target that runs after the build to copy the content of the the output directory (`bin\debug`) to the destination directory that I need. This approach has some issues:

1. It does not scale well if I need to add more projects with different deployment requirements.
2. If the projects are built in parallel then they both need to copy `log4net.dll` to the same location. If this happens at the same time then I get warnings because the file is in use and retries are attempted. It works eventually, but I take it as a hint that I am doing something wrong. To workaround this I could filter the project output to deploy only what is produced by the project - which means I am able to deploy only `myconsole.exe` and `plugin.dll`, but not `log4net.dll`. I would have to deploy this one manually, probably after being done with both projects (solution-level event?). This seems too complicated...

What is the correct way to implement this in MSBuild?

Comment: I think if you want the `log4net` will be in a separated dir, You'll have to load it by reflection too.

Comment: You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55982108/839513) Q&A to know how to output the reference to the subfolder.

Comment: But in general, what is your question? Do you ask how to output the reference? This question was answered by the link I gave. Do you ask how to build `dll` to different dir and load it by reflection?

Comment: I am only interested in how to change the reference output using MSBuild. Thank you @Baruch for pointing it out to me. You may want to add this as an answer that I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you ask a few questions:

- How to output the references to a separate folder.
- How to export a `dll` without its references.

## How to output the references to a separate folder

This question has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946010/how-to-specify-output-folder-for-the-referenced-nuget-packages), and its answer is somewhat complex, so it is not worth duplicating it.

## How to export a `dll` without its references

You don't want `plugin.dll` to use its own `log4net.dll`, because if there is a static field in `log4net.dll`, it will be reinitialized when you load the `plugin.dll` at runtime.

Therefore, although you are exporting the `plugin.dll` to a separate folder, you need to leave the `dll`s in your executable folder:

Add this to your `plugin.csproj` file:

```xml
<Target Name="DontCopyReferencesToLocal" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Remove="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

---

### Disclaimer:

I have not checked how the combination of the 2 requirements works together.
But I think that as long as each of them works on its own, there is no reason why they should not work together.

Comment: My question is how to output a reference to a specific folder. The other thing that you mention "how to export a dll without its references" is not what I had in mind, but it doesn't hurt to learn. Thank you.

Comment: @Suiden Your question was not focused and included more topics.