# How to move referenced dlls to another folder C#

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm trying to use CefSharp's Chromium Browser, but I don't want a clunk of files from cefsharp in its startup folder. I want to keep it in the `bin` folder, I don't know how.

Sorry, I'm a newbie at VS and all.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the files in a subfolder? The files are copied to the bin folder by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution to your problem. You can use the `<probing`> element in your run-time configuration, for specifying where to search for your assemblies, like in this example below, taken from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```xml
    <configuration>  
        <runtime>  
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
                <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>  
            </assemblyBinding>  
        </runtime>  
    </configuration>
```

**EDIT**:
The rest of the answer is in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55946010/how-to-specify-output-folder-for-the-referenced-nuget-packages).

Comment: is "bin;bin2\subbin;bin3" where I put the folder?

Comment: Those are example relative paths to your executable, there's where you need to put the names of your output folders.

Comment: so my folder is `bin` so is it `"bin"`?