# Nuget installation directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuspec

I made my .net framework project into a nuget package. I want to install that nuget package in another project, but I need to specify exactly where that nuget should be installed e.g (Shell/someDir/**here**). I understand that I have to edit the .nuspec but with what command?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't get control over where nuget packages are installed in a target project. When nuget packages are installed, they are unpacked into either the `packages` folder inside the project, or into a folder inside the current user home directory (depending on which version of the .Net framework is being used). You can copy files out during installation, which might help with your use case. Can you expand further on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, the scenario that I currently have is that I have a Shell project and in that project at compile time, a copy of my other projects is placed in a specific folder (Shell/someDir/here). And that is how my projects work now. The thing i am trying to achieve by nugetifying my projects is so they can be easily reused. Currently when I install my nugetified project in Shell, it places all files in main directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer I needed in this thread

> [Is it possible to change the location of packages for NuGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092759/is-it-possible-to-change-the-location-of-packages-for-nuget)

I added in my Nuget.Config file and it copied the nuget files successfully

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\myteam\teampackages" />
  </config>
  ... 
</configuration>
```